# java code to expand each column to fit text (autofit function)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have existing java code that will grab a table generated in the application and export it to Excel spreadsheet, but right now it is writing to the Excel spreadsheet as is, without any formatting. I would like to be able to add to the java code to expand each column (like double clicking the column in Excel) to fit the text. How do I achieve that?

heres the part of the code that writes to the excel spreadsheet

```
    /**
 *  This method writes data to the row.
 *
 *  @param header   The header row for the data to be written.
 *
 *  @param data     The data rows to be written.
 *
 *  @param rowIndex The starting index for the row.
 *
 *  @param columnIndex  The starting index for the column.
 *
 *  @throws IOException The file cannot be written to.
 *
 *  @throws FileNotFoundException   The file cannot be found or open.
 */

private HSSFSheet dataSheet;
private int processDataToSheet(List<Excel_o> header, List<List<Excel_o>> data, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
                    throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
{
    //process header data
    processRowData(dataSheet, rowIndex, header, columnIndex);

    //write data to sheet
    for(List<Excel_o> singleList: data){
        //process data for the whole row.
        processRowData(dataSheet, ++rowIndex, singleList, columnIndex);
    }

    return rowIndex;
}
```

I looked up the methods available for apachi.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet (the datasheet variable in my code) and it says it has a method called autoSizeColumn, but when I looked at the drop down in my Eclipse, there is no such option available. Is there a reason why this is the case?

Comment: what do you exactly want ?? please show something, that you have come up.

Comment: Are you using Apache POI to generate Excels in Java?

Comment: yes im using apache poi to generate Excels

Answer (score 1):

You could use the autoSizeColumn() method, see API reference [here](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#autoSizeColumn%28int%29)

Comment: the problem is that for some reason it is not a an option in the list of dropdown after i type in datasheet.

Comment: Have you made sure you're using a new enough copy of Apache POI? I'd strongly suggest you try upgrading to POI 3.9 and trying with that, the answer should then work just fine!